# Construct 95% lower CI for proportion of adults who voted poor. Of 1060 adults, 54% voted poor environment.

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I know that the lower CI will be theta - Z(alpha/2)*sigma.

The value for Z is 1.96 because it is a 95% CI, but I am not sure how to find theta and sigma. The only other piece of information was that we can use 0.05 for alpha if we are testing to see if the majority of the nations adults think the environment is poor.

Do I need to do an upper tail test to find theta? How would one do that?

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a 95% confidence interval with a lower bound will be 
$p - z^*\sqrt{p(1-p)/n},$ where $p = .45,$ $n = 1060,$ and $z^* = 1.645$ cuts 95% from the upper tail of a standard normal distribution.

This gives $0.5148181 \approx 51.5\%.$ The interpretation is we
have 95% confidence that more than 51.5% of individuals in the
population (from which the sample was taken) feel their environment is 'poor'.

*Clarifications:*  Some of these formulas may be in your text:

(1) If you were doing a two-sided 95% confidence interval, you would
want to cut 2.5% from each tail of the standard normal curve--for
a total of 5% in both tails, leaving 95% in the center. 
A two-sided 95% CI would be based on $p \pm 1.96\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$

(2) The $\sigma$ in your formula is intended to be an estimate
of the $SD(p)$, the sample proportion of 'poor' answers. It arises
as follows. Let $X$ be the number of people answering 'poor'.
Then $X \sim Bin(n, \theta)$, where $\theta$ is the population proportion of 'poor'. A point estimate of $\theta$ is $p = X/n.$
The variance of $X$ is $V(X) = n\theta(1 - \theta)$ and the variance of $p = X/n$ is $V(p) = \sigma^2 = \theta(1-\theta)/n$, estimated
by $\hat \sigma^2 = p(1-p)/n$. Thus $\hat \sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$